# How to find who — or what — exactly opened ad page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware, malware-detection

Recently I noticed that sometimes in my Chrome somewhat opens new tabs with ads. It comes with a random interval (0-1-2-3 times in a day). It comes if I'm browsing or wathcing a video on youtube in fullscreen or even I'm doing something in another app.

At first, I thought that it could be malware at my Mac, but in several days the same problem appeared on my Windows PC. I think this is a bad chrome extension because this is only common between mac and PC (extensions synchronized via google account).

I tried to look into sources of ad page and into the network tab but didn't find anything suspicious. I have about 15 extensions and turning them off one by one to figure out which one is bad is too painful for me (as I said ad pages open randomly).

Is there a way to figure out who or what opened a new tab in google chrome?